# What should happen when you specify an inline style attribute of an empty string?

Tags: css

If you have something like this:

```
<h1 style="color:;"></h1>
```

will it ignore that and use whatever color would have otherwise been used if there was no inline style?

Comment: Just like any invalid syntax in CSS, it is ignored.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n2s7ro9d/

Comment: I saw this happen so I was wondering what the expected behavior of malformed content like this is. I wonder if the down voter read too much into the question and thought I was going to do this on purpose? Cause that would be dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rule cant be parsed, it is ignored

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2s7ro9d/)

[Per the `w3c` spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors)

> Malformed declarations. User agents must handle unexpected tokens
>   encountered while parsing a declaration by reading until the end of
>   the declaration, while observing the rules for matching pairs of (),
>   [], {}, "", and '', and correctly handling escapes. For example, a
>   **malformed declaration may be missing a** property name, colon (:), or
>   property **value**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be ignored.

For this kind of thing though, instead of asking a question, I recommend just trying it. Slap it together in a test page and load it up in all the browsers. Even if the standards text disagrees, if all the browsers do the same thing, that doesn't really matter. Real world websites are loaded by Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari so if all four of them do the same thing (or even close to the same thing), that's a de-facto standard answer.